# How do I produce a stacked bar chart from a table with two indexes?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have this data frame in Python:

| Class | Grade | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | A | 5 |
|  | B | 6 |
|  | C | 5 |
| Two | A | 4 |
|  | B | 3 |
|  | C | 4 |
| Three | A | 7 |
|  | B | 3 |
|  | C | 2 |

And I would like to produce a stacked bar chart, with Count on the y axis, and classes on the X axis (One, Two, Three). Each bar stacking the A, B, C Counts to give an ABC total per class.
Something like this:

[image]

How would I do this with matplotlib?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible input for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 3 columns, you can [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) the missing values, then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
(df.replace('', np.nan).ffill()
   .pivot(index='Class', columns='Grade', values='Count')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

If you have a MultiIndex with a single column either `unstack` or:

```
(df.reset_index()
   .pivot(index='Class', columns='Grade', values='Count')
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Used input:

```
   Class Grade  Count
0    One     A      5
1            B      6
2            C      5
3    Two     A      4
4            B      3
5            C      4
6  Three     A      7
7            B      3
8            C      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is Multiindex use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df['Count'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: pic]

Data:

```
print (df)
             Count
Class Grade       
One   A          5
      B          6
      C          5
Two   A          4
      B          3
      C          4
Three A          7
      B          3
      C          2
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([(  'One', 'A'),
            (  'One', 'B'),
            (  'One', 'C'),
            (  'Two', 'A'),
            (  'Two', 'B'),
            (  'Two', 'C'),
            ('Three', 'A'),
            ('Three', 'B'),
            ('Three', 'C')],
           names=['Class', 'Grade'])
```